# Default values when adding a new record

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to add a new record with the Binding Navigator Add button. I have three fields that can be defaulted on the new record. UserId, Start time and End Time. Using the code below I am able to set the Start and End time but not the User Combobox. Is it not possible to set this value?

I have tried setting the value in the BindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click

```
Private Sub BindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BindingNavigatorAddNewItem.Click
    'MsgBox("Add new Log")
    Dim User As String = currUser.Name
    Dim Index As Integer = cmbOperator.FindString(User)
    cmbOperator.SelectedIndex = Index
    cmbOperator.SelectedItem = User

    dtpLogIn_Date.Value = currUser.Start_Time
    dtpLogOut_Date.Value = currUser.End_Time

End Sub
```

[Form after add new redraw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qBal.png)

Comment: What is currUser? How did you fill the cmbOperator? Is FindString actually finding and returning an index?

Comment: @CharlesMay `FindString` will always return a value even if not found, the string is nothing etc. and that value is (-1)...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ, Sure, but if it is indeed returning -1 the combobox will never show  a selection and that is why I'm asking more or less if the OP knows what is being returned from it. I could have worded it better but am at least trying to trigger some information that we can't get to reading the code provided.

Comment: @CharlesMay agreed, OP needs to provide some more information as you mentioned.

Comment: cmbOperator.SelectedIndex is set to 1 before the before the refresh. When the screen reappears cmbOperator is blank. I really need it to contain the current operator as one of the requirments is a operator can only update their own records. Therefore this field is disabled except for supervisors.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to set the cmbOperator index in the BindingSource_PositionChanged event. My guess is this fires after the record position changed. Then I wrapped it in code to check if the was a add new. Probably could have put it in the BindingNavigator_PositionChanged as well.

```
    Dim varShiftKey = Shift_LogBindingSource.Current("Shift_Key")
    If varShiftKey = -1 Then
        Dim User As String = currUser.Name
        Dim Index As Integer = cmbOperator.FindString(User)
        cmbOperator.SelectedIndex = Index
    End If
```